# Is it correct that a wallet which does PoW never needs to call attachToTangle?

Tags: wallet, iri-node, iri-legacy-api

This is more or less to confirm my deeper understanding of IRI and how it all works.

From the docs and the code what I see is, that `attachToTangle` outsources the PoW to a node. It is `broadcastTransactions` what sends a "complete" transaction (**including** the Pow) to the network.

If this is correct, I assume, that a wallet which does PoW itself, never needs to call the `attachToTangle` API.

Is this all correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is all correct.

Don't forget to `storeTrnsactions` before you broadcast them, or your own node may not have them later for reference.

Comment: I upvoted these question and answer and also [these](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/943/where-is-pow-being-executed-when-using-the-cli-wallet) because they illuminate an important question. It could be useful to recap all things in a scheme.