# Can the official GUI IOTA wallet also delegate its PoW to a full node?

Tags: wallet, iri-node, pow

I have setup a full node myself and made sure the attachToTangle command is remotely available. I was assuming the IOTA wallet would outsource its PoW then instead of doing it himself (by means of CCurl or Webgl).

But my transactions do not seem faster? How come?

Comment: The wallet does always do the POW by default as far as I know. Don't know of a way to outsource it to the node (there are very few nodes who allow that anyway). Might be possible with the command line wallet.

Comment: @WernerderChamp i think you are right. this related [question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/943/where-is-pow-being-executed-when-using-the-cli-wallet?rq=1) affirms. it would be nice though to make this also configurable in the GUI wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Desktop GUI wallet, as far as I know there is no way to set PoW to be done on the fullnode.  But the Cli Wallet and the Android Wallet the default PoW is done on the fullnode.

Answer (score 0):

Official gui wallet will do PoW on the full node if it's on localhost (address in config is http://localhost:14265). If you have a remote node 
you can use it as local by making ssh tunnel to it so it is accessible on localhost:14265 address.