# Cli-Wallet error: COMMAND attachToTangle is not available on this node

Tags: cli-wallet, iri-node

I tried to generate new addresses. During registration in the tangle following happened:

```
iota (http://PrivateNode:Port ✓) 0ι : address

One minute while we generate the address.
The address is HXHFQWQMJCXUYDMJGCDMMSHKHNOKAHZFELKQPKVBTMYMIJNDVPGZDMMZICTQ999GALTPIKIVKUFEOZXLCUAYGATIF9
Now we will register that address into the iota tangle.  One moment.

Error: Request Error: COMMAND attachToTangle is not available on this node
```

What is the reason for that? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do the POW on client side, because the Cli-Wallet is not able to do POW. So either you search for a node, which does the POW for you ([here](http://iota.dance/nodes)), or you do enable the POW on your own node, which is explained in this [thread](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/how-do-i-enable-my-fullnode-to-do-pow).

Sources:

[Where is POW being executed when using the cli-wallet?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/943/where-is-pow-being-executed-when-using-the-cli-wallet)

[Github Issue: Transfer failed](https://github.com/MichaelSchwab/iota-commandline-wallet/issues/6)