# How do I enable my fullnode to do POW?

Tags: iri-node

It is basically all in the title. What iri settings are needed to delegate my POW to my Fullnode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable POW in your fullnode just open this file in a Texteditor like nano:

```
nano /home/iota/node/iota.ini
```

You will see this:

```
[IRI]
PORT = 14265
UDP_RECEIVER_PORT = 14600
TCP_RECEIVER_PORT = 15600
API_HOST = 0.0.0.0
IXI_DIR = ixi
HEADLESS = true
DEBUG = false
TESTNET = false
DB_PATH = mainnetdb
RESCAN_DB = false

REMOTE_LIMIT_API = "removeNeighbors, addNeighbors, interruptAttachingToTangle, attachToTangle, getNeighbors, setApiRateLimit"

NEIGHBORS = udp://IP:PORT 
EOF
```

Just delete attachToTangle and interruptAttachingToTangle under REMOTE_LIMIT_API, so it looks like:

```
REMOTE_LIMIT_API = "removeNeighbors, addNeighbors, getNeighbors, setApiRateLimit"
```

Now you have to restart you Fullnode using the command:

```
sudo service iota start
```

That's it. Now your fullnode can do POW.

Comment: is `IRI_OPTIONS = "--remote"` obsolete?

Comment: Following [link](http://www.iota.partners/) there is no need for `IRI_OPTIONS = "--remote"` and enabling POW like given, was sufficient for me.

Comment: Good to know. I found by setting it, the `API_HOST` ist set to `0.0.0.0`, basically what you specified explicitly. https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/cb69f467744db4c52429b647824da5863c6501f3/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/IRI.java#L176